# How to get mod_mono.so in Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: monodevelop, mod-mono

I have installed MONO from http://monodevelop.com/Download and installed the Mono framework MRE and MDK. I am trying to get this to work in Apache on OS X 10.9. I see I need the mod_mono.so for Apache but I can not see it in the downloads section. How do I get or compile mod_mono.so for Apache?

Answer (score 2):

I am a novice with mono but followed some instructions. I downloaded and installed everything from here: 
http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

To get Apache to work with mod_mono.so I downloaded source from this page: 
http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mod_mono/

You have to compile it. I went into the unpacked directory and wrote this in termminal:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

This puts the mod_mono.so in correct Apache dir and the mod_mono.conf file. To include it you must add this to your httpd.conf (I put it at the end of the file):

```
 # mod_mono_configuration                                                  
 Include /etc/apache2/mod_mono.conf
 MonoServerPath /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mod-mono-server2
```

Comment: Thanks Asle, worked like a charm (just replaced mod-mono-server2 by mod-mono-server4)

Comment: Thanks Alse you saved my day. As soon as I switched to mod-mono-server4 worked for me too. While If I use mod-mono-server or mod-mono-server2 I get Cannot open assembly '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.1/lib/mono/2.0/mod-mono-server2.exe': No such file or directory.
What should I have to do to run an older framework version?